# What is wrong with this proof that P≠NP?

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification, fake-proofs

Proof by contradiction:

Assume that $P=NP$.

There must exist a function that maps from NP to P.

So there must exist a function $T$ that,
given the source code of a polynomial-time verifier function $V$ (which is a representation of the problem in $NP$),
can compute the corresponding polynomial-time solution-finder function $S$ (which is a representation of the problem in $P$).

So $S = T(V)$ and $V(x, S(x))$ is true for all valid $x$.

Construct $V_1$ like this:

```
V_1(x, y) {
    // x: input
    // y: solution to be verified

    S_1 = T(V_1); // this step runs in constant time
    if( S_1(x) == y ) return 'wrong'; // this step runs in polynomial time
    else return 'correct';
}
```

$V_1$ runs in polynomial time (of the length of $x$) because the $S_1 = T(V_1)$ step runs in constant time
and $S_1(x)$ runs in polynomial time (of the length of $x$).

Since $V_1$ is a polynomial-time verifier,
the $S_1$ produced by $T(V_1)$ should always be able to find a solution $V_1$ verifies as correct.
But with our $V_1$, the solution $S_1$ finds for any input will always be wrong.

This is a contradiction.
So no function $T$ that can compute the polynomial-time solution finder given the polynomial-time verifier exists.

So no function can connect $NP$ to $P$.

So $P≠NP$.

---

Is the logic that there must exist a function $T$ that 'connect' $NP$ to $P$ flawed?

Or maybe $T$ exists but doesn't run in finite time?

Comment: Why would $T$ exist ? That's something that may be true, but you should justify it !

Comment: @MaximeRamzi The way I see it is if P and NP are the same, there should be a function (call it T) that maps from NP (the verifier) to the corresponding P (the solution-finder). Is this flawed?

Comment: Well this function exists but what makes you think it is computable ?

Comment: @wisha [Choice functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) aren't computable in general.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi T being incomputable makes sense. But wouldn't this mean that it is impossible to find polynomial-time solvers for all NP problems? So P may equal NP, but we'll never get the polynomial-time solutions?

Comment: Well maybe not, but maybe. If someone proves P=NP by actually exhibiting a polynomial time solution to a known NP-complete problem, then we will actually get the polynomial time solutions (albeit probably all very inefficient)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi The steps to prove a polynomial time solution to an NP-complete problem could be used as a method to transform the NP-complete problem into a polynomial-time solution. Combining this with the established process to transform NP problems to NP-complete would give us *a method to transform any NP problems to their polynomial-time solutions*, which is the same thing as a computable T.

Comment: The proof wouldn't *need* to do that, although there seems to be a subtlety which may allow you to prove that such a $T$ exists

Comment: I did not verify the method in the proof in detail, but this looks like something like Cantor's diagonal method. If the method works independently of whether oracles are allowed or not it is well known that the method cannot solve the problem. This rules out most traditional proof techniques.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Musn't a proof that two functions correspond to each other show that one can be transforms into the other? Also, if a polynomial time solution to an NP-complete problem result in a proof that computable T exists, than the P≠NP proof in my post would be valid and produce a contradiction.

Comment: @Peter What is the oracle in this case?

Comment: What I mean : If the method nowhere involves an oracle it cannot prove $P\ne NP$ which is the main reason for the difficulty of this problem. Don't ask me why ? I have not understood it either, but I trust the source I have (German site : "Joerg Resag-Die Grenzen der Berechenbarkeit")

Comment: In particular methods similar to Cantor's diagonal method are doomed to fail (additionally, such an approach has surely been tried by many other mathematicians)

Comment: @Peter So T is my oracle here, as the actual function is most likely uncomputable as Maxime said. But does the actual T being uncomputable imply that it is impossible to find polynomial-time solvers for all NP problems? So P may equal NP, but we'll never know all the polynomial-time algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there might be multiple solutions certifying solvability of NP problem.  For most of NP complex problems, the function T that searches all the solution space and verifies it by V would be fine, but running in exponentional time due to the number of possible inputs.

Provided NP=P it would be sufficient to find an polynomial algorithm that for given problem tells if there is one certificating instance that solves it. However you would not break into much treasuries using that algorithm.

The other question would be if there must be polynomial algorithm to find the certification. And even if it would be the case, it still does not as far as I know mean that it will be a polynomial function of certificating function.

Going further you constructed the problem for which you know that there exist no pair $V_1$, $S_1$ that would solve it. So if your T is clever enough it will print the output "there is no such S to solve this recursive ill posed problem":)

Comment: I don't quite understand the 'certificating instance' here. Does it mean a solver that works for a single input? Also, the contradictory V_1 wouldn't have been possible if S_1 doesn't run in polynomial time. So isn't the only way to avoid contradiction to say P=NP?